# is there any way to decode javascript hex code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I understand it and rewrite it in simple javascript code? can anyone help me in decoding the code or can you convert it original script?

What kind of method we need to using to decode javascript if some one obfuscated it?

```
var _$_5a93=["\x2F\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x6F\x79\x65\x65\x73\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x2F","\x47\x45\x54","\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x74\x69\x70","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x74\x69\x70\x22\x5D","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x54\x61\x62\x6C\x65","\x23\x78\x69\x6E\x5F\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x32","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x3D\x22\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x68\x72\x6D\x22\x5D","\x31\x30\x30\x25","\x79\x79\x2D\x6D\x6D\x2D\x64\x64","\x31\x39\x36\x30\x3A","\x67\x65\x74\x46\x75\x6C\x6C\x59\x65\x61\x72","\x64\x61\x74\x65\x70\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72","\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6F\x66\x5F\x62\x69\x72\x74\x68","\x31\x39\x39\x30\x3A","\x3A","\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6F\x66\x5F\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x69\x6E\x67","\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74","\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x73\x65\x72\x69\x61\x6C\x69\x7A\x65","\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x32\x26\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3D","\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72","","\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65","\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x2E\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74","\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x72\x65\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x61\x70\x69","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x23\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x5F\x72\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x64","\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x2E\x62\x73\x2E\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x5F\x69\x64","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x2F\x72\x65\x61\x64\x2F","\x6A\x64\x3D\x31\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x6D\x6F\x64\x65\x3D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x26\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3D\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x26\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x5F\x69\x64\x3D","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x23\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x5F\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x6F\x6E","\x2E\x65\x64\x69\x74\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x2D\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x2F\x64\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F","\x76\x61\x6C","\x23\x64\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x67\x65\x74","\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x23\x61\x6A\x5F\x64\x65\x70\x61\x72\x74\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64","\x70\x72\x6F\x70","\x2E\x73\x61\x76\x65","\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x61\x64\x64\x5F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x6F\x79\x65\x65\x26\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3D","\x73\x6C\x6F\x77","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74","\x2E\x61\x64\x64\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x72\x65\x73\x65\x74","\x23\x78\x69\x6E\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x2E\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x72\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x64\x2D\x69\x64","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x5F\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x5D","\x2F\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x2F"];$(document)[_$_5a93[63]](function(){var a=$(_$_5a93[5])[_$_5a93[4]]({"\x62\x44\x65\x73\x74\x72\x6F\x79":true,"\x61\x6A\x61\x78":{url:base_url+ _$_5a93[0],type:_$_5a93[1]},"\x66\x6E\x44\x72\x61\x77\x43\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B":function(b){$(_$_5a93[3])[_$_5a93[2]]()}});$(_$_5a93[9])[_$_5a93[8]]($(this)[_$_5a93[7]](_$_5a93[6]));$(_$_5a93[9])[_$_5a93[8]]({width:_$_5a93[10]});$(_$_5a93[15])[_$_5a93[14]]({changeMonth:true,changeYear:true,dateFormat:_$_5a93[11],yearRange:_$_5a93[12]+ new Date()[_$_5a93[13]]()});$(_$_5a93[18])[_$_5a93[14]]({changeMonth:true,changeYear:true,dateFormat:_$_5a93[11],yearRange:_$_5a93[16]+ _$_5a93[17]+ new Date()[_$_5a93[13]]()});$(_$_5a93[37])[_$_5a93[36]](function(d){d[_$_5a93[19]]();var f=$(this),c=f[_$_5a93[7]](_$_5a93[20]);$[_$_5a93[34]]({type:_$_5a93[21],url:d[_$_5a93[23]][_$_5a93[22]],data:f[_$_5a93[24]]()+ _$_5a93[25]+ c,cache:false,success:function(g){if(g[_$_5a93[26]]!= _$_5a93[27]){toastr[_$_5a93[26]](g[_$_5a93[26]])}else {$(_$_5a93[30])[_$_5a93[29]](_$_5a93[28]);a[_$_5a93[35]]()[_$_5a93[34]][_$_5a93[33]](function(){toastr[_$_5a93[32]](g[_$_5a93[31]])},true)}}})});$(_$_5a93[47])[_$_5a93[46]](_$_5a93[38],function(i){var h=$(i[_$_5a93[39]]);var k=h[_$_5a93[41]](_$_5a93[40]);var j=$(this);$[_$_5a93[34]]({url:base_url+ _$_5a93[42],type:_$_5a93[1],data:_$_5a93[43]+ k,success:function(l){if(l){$(_$_5a93[45])[_$_5a93[44]](l)}}})});jQuery(_$_5a93[53])[_$_5a93[52]](function(){jQuery[_$_5a93[51]](base_url+ _$_5a93[48]+ jQuery(this)[_$_5a93[49]](),function(m,n){jQuery(_$_5a93[50])[_$_5a93[44]](m)})});$(_$_5a93[62])[_$_5a93[36]](function(d){d[_$_5a93[19]]();var f=$(this),c=f[_$_5a93[7]](_$_5a93[20]);$(_$_5a93[56])[_$_5a93[55]](_$_5a93[54],true);$[_$_5a93[34]]({type:_$_5a93[21],url:d[_$_5a93[23]][_$_5a93[22]],data:f[_$_5a93[24]]()+ _$_5a93[57]+ c,cache:false,success:function(g){if(g[_$_5a93[26]]!= _$_5a93[27]){toastr[_$_5a93[26]](g[_$_5a93[26]]);$(_$_5a93[56])[_$_5a93[55]](_$_5a93[54],false)}else {a[_$_5a93[35]]()[_$_5a93[34]][_$_5a93[33]](function(){toastr[_$_5a93[32]](g[_$_5a93[31]])},true);$(_$_5a93[60])[_$_5a93[59]](_$_5a93[58]);$(_$_5a93[62])[0][_$_5a93[61]]();$(_$_5a93[56])[_$_5a93[55]](_$_5a93[54],false)}}})})});$(document)[_$_5a93[46]](_$_5a93[64],_$_5a93[65],function(){$(_$_5a93[67])[_$_5a93[49]]($(this)[_$_5a93[41]](_$_5a93[66]));$(_$_5a93[37])[_$_5a93[7]](_$_5a93[22],base_url+ _$_5a93[68]+ $(this)[_$_5a93[41]](_$_5a93[66]))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code has a lot more information than the encoded array. If you want to decode the array data, just do a `console.log()`.

Check the following snippet:

```js
var x = ["\x2F\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x6F\x79\x65\x65\x73\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x2F","\x47\x45\x54","\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x74\x69\x70","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x74\x69\x70\x22\x5D","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x54\x61\x62\x6C\x65","\x23\x78\x69\x6E\x5F\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x32","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x3D\x22\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x68\x72\x6D\x22\x5D","\x31\x30\x30\x25","\x79\x79\x2D\x6D\x6D\x2D\x64\x64","\x31\x39\x36\x30\x3A","\x67\x65\x74\x46\x75\x6C\x6C\x59\x65\x61\x72","\x64\x61\x74\x65\x70\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72","\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6F\x66\x5F\x62\x69\x72\x74\x68","\x31\x39\x39\x30\x3A","\x3A","\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6F\x66\x5F\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x69\x6E\x67","\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74","\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x73\x65\x72\x69\x61\x6C\x69\x7A\x65","\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x32\x26\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3D","\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72","","\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65","\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x2E\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74","\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x72\x65\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x61\x70\x69","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x23\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x5F\x72\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x64","\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x2E\x62\x73\x2E\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x5F\x69\x64","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x2F\x72\x65\x61\x64\x2F","\x6A\x64\x3D\x31\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x6D\x6F\x64\x65\x3D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x26\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3D\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x26\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x5F\x69\x64\x3D","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x23\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x5F\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x6F\x6E","\x2E\x65\x64\x69\x74\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x2D\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x2F\x64\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F","\x76\x61\x6C","\x23\x64\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x67\x65\x74","\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x23\x61\x6A\x5F\x64\x65\x70\x61\x72\x74\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64","\x70\x72\x6F\x70","\x2E\x73\x61\x76\x65","\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x61\x64\x64\x5F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x6F\x79\x65\x65\x26\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3D","\x73\x6C\x6F\x77","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74","\x2E\x61\x64\x64\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x72\x65\x73\x65\x74","\x23\x78\x69\x6E\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x2E\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x72\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x64\x2D\x69\x64","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x5F\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x5D","\x2F\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x2F"]

x.forEach(item => console.log(item))
```

Comment: can you convert it original script?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I could decode the data contained in the array. Bug the original script has a lot more information, like functions.

Answer (score 0):

To docode  `\x2F` use `.toString()`

```js
var _$_5a93 = `["\x2F\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x6F\x79\x65\x65\x73\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x2F","\x47\x45\x54","\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x74\x69\x70","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x74\x69\x70\x22\x5D","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x54\x61\x62\x6C\x65","\x23\x78\x69\x6E\x5F\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x32","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x3D\x22\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x68\x72\x6D\x22\x5D","\x31\x30\x30\x25","\x79\x79\x2D\x6D\x6D\x2D\x64\x64","\x31\x39\x36\x30\x3A","\x67\x65\x74\x46\x75\x6C\x6C\x59\x65\x61\x72","\x64\x61\x74\x65\x70\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72","\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6F\x66\x5F\x62\x69\x72\x74\x68","\x31\x39\x39\x30\x3A","\x3A","\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6F\x66\x5F\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x69\x6E\x67","\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74","\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x73\x65\x72\x69\x61\x6C\x69\x7A\x65","\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x32\x26\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3D","\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72","","\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65","\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x2E\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74","\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x72\x65\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x61\x70\x69","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x23\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x5F\x72\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x64","\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x2E\x62\x73\x2E\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x5F\x69\x64","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x2F\x72\x65\x61\x64\x2F","\x6A\x64\x3D\x31\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x6D\x6F\x64\x65\x3D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x26\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3D\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x26\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x5F\x69\x64\x3D","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x23\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x5F\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x6F\x6E","\x2E\x65\x64\x69\x74\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x2D\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x2F\x64\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F","\x76\x61\x6C","\x23\x64\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x67\x65\x74","\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x23\x61\x6A\x5F\x64\x65\x70\x61\x72\x74\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64","\x70\x72\x6F\x70","\x2E\x73\x61\x76\x65","\x26\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x61\x64\x64\x5F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x6F\x79\x65\x65\x26\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3D","\x73\x6C\x6F\x77","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74","\x2E\x61\x64\x64\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x72\x65\x73\x65\x74","\x23\x78\x69\x6E\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x2E\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x72\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x64\x2D\x69\x64","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x5F\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x5D","\x2F\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x2F"]`;

// finds and replaces the \x..
var deob = _$_5a93.replace(/(\\x[a-f0-9])/gi, function(m){
  return m[1].toString()
})
console.log(`_$_5a93 = ${deob}`)
```

its not simple task to restore to original code, you need find the deobfuscator out there